# Magento 2 data migration Destination documents are not mapped: TABLE 346

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, magento2-migration-tool, delta-migration

I'm doing data migration from magento 1 to magento 2 and it gives this error, can you please let me know the solution for this error

```
[2017-11-15 07:45:45][ERROR]: Destination documents are not mapped: TABLE 346,TABLE 347,TABLE 348,TABLE 359,TABLE 360
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, i have make these steps, it will solve the issue,

```
<step title="Customer Attributes Step">
         <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
         <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
         <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
     </step>

    <step title="Map Step">
         <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
         <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
         <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
     </step>
     <step title="OrderGrids Step">
         <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
         <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
         <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
     </step>
     <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
         <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
         <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
         <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
     </step>
```

and also i have add few ignore in my map.xml. for e.g.

```
<ignore>
                <document>TABLE 346</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>TABLE 347</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>TABLE 348</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>TABLE 359</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>TABLE 360</document>
            </ignore>
```

before i start this migration, these tables are not there i was wondering how these tables were created in my M2 database.

Now i have successfully migrated sales order from M1 to M2.

Comment: In which fine you added above code?

Comment: vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.x/config.xml, 1.x is the version of your M1. In this file add steps <step>....

Comment: vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.x/map.xml, In this file add the ignore table names, which you want to ignore during migration. for example vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.0.1/map.xml